# React template mouse event fires after container's mouse event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, mouseevent

I've came across with such problem:
There are parent element with mousedown handler and child elements.

If I add child element by creating React template with mousedown handler inside

```
  var mousedown = function(e) { console.log('child-2: mousedown') };
  var childTemplate = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return React.createElement("rect", {id:  "child-2", x: "220", y: "220", width: "30", height: "30", onMouseDown:  mousedown,  fill: "blue"});
    }
  });

  var template  = React.createElement(childTemplate, {});
  ReactDOM.render(template, document.getElementById('area'));
```

then parent mousedown fires before child event [(jsfiddle example)](https://jsfiddle.net/g7qtqcty/)

Is there a way to force child `mousedown` first (and prevent parent's `mousedown` with `e.stopPropagation` for example) without rewriting everything in react template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using jQuery for some event handlers and React for the other, the order of events cannot really be managed with just `e.stopPropagation`. Not even event bubbling worked as far as I know based on some tests I did.

A solution to this would be either to use React to manage everything, but if that's not an option, you could explicitly check which component you're clicking on and stop the `parent` from running if needed.

For example:

```
$('#parent').unbind('mousedown').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
  if(e.target.id != "parent") return; //if not "#parent" don't proceed.
  console.log('parent: mousedown');
});
```

By passing the event object to the event handler, you can check which element was clicked on. If we clicked on *any* element that's not `parent`, then return out. If the element clicked *does* have the `parent` id, then it will do the console log.

Here's a full demo: [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g7qtqcty/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent').unbind('mousedown').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id != "parent") return;
    console.log('parent: mousedown');
  });

  $('#child-1').on('mousedown', function() {
    console.log('child-1: mousedown');
  });

  var mousedown = function(e) { 
    console.log('child-2: mousedown')
  };

  var childTemplate = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return React.createElement("rect", {id:  "child-2", x: "220", y: "220", width: "30", height: "30", onMouseDown:  mousedown,  fill: "blue"});
    }
  });

  var template  = React.createElement(childTemplate, {});
  ReactDOM.render(template, document.getElementById('area'));
});
```

Comment: I was afraid of it. Could you say please whether it's really a bug (feature) of react or it's a common expected behavior ?
Thank you anyway for your detailed answer

Comment: I can't say for sure, but jQuery isn't really meant to work with Reactjs, nor vice versa. So it's not a bug (because they aren't designed to work together) but it's also not a deliberate effect.